# :focus simultaneously with input of button and search

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am attempting to give an input of text and an button pseudo :focus. I can do that, no problem. What is my problem is though is I want when I click on the input of text, that it not only  changes the elements on the input text but also the button. Is this possible in JS? Would you just create a function saying when that is clicked change the elements of that? Or even in jQuery?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant HTML, so that we can tell what (if any) structural relationship exists between the elements in question.

Comment: This was solved with the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes:

```
#inputText:focus{
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
#inputText:focus ~ #button {
  background: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fxzuu3yz/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for a jQuery way of doing this:

```js
function update() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
}

$(".main input").on("focus", update);
$(".main input").on("blur", update);
```

```css
.active input {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.active button {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Go!</button>
</div>
```